# upload on page image in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to upload image on page using ajax in codeigniter? On form image needs to be uploaded then
user should fill further information. I try ajax but unable to figure out simplest way

Comment: You're going to need to give us a lot more information. What's the code that handles the upload on the CI/JS side? What _precisely_ do you want to happen when the upload completes? Is the upload even working? Are you using the CI Form/Upload class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/

This is how I did it for the first time, easier than it might look and should work without too much problems.